# How to know exact flex sdk version from existing project files?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I received an inheritance old flex project. I've never worked with Flex. I installed the latest Flash Builder and I need to know the exact version of used Flex SDK. Is there any way to know used SDK version from project files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it's an AIR project, you can open up the -app.xml, based on which the project is built and check out the application namespace

`<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.0">`

Represents AIR 1.0 (Flex SDK 3.2)

`<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0">`

Represents an AIR 2.0 Project (SDK 4.0 ?)

If it's a WebProject (that runs on FlashPlayer), check the `.actionScriptProperties` file in your project. In one of my project files, under the `compiler` tag, I can find a property called `flexSDK="Flex 3.2"`. Not sure if this will be there for every project, as i could not find the same property for other projects.

One more thing you can check is the target FlashPlayer version you are going to compile against. Check the `htmlPlayerVersion` property of the `compiler` tag in your `.actionScriptProperties` file.

If the htmlPlayerVersion is greater than or equal to `10.0.0`, you should use Flex SDK 3.2 or above.

Comment: No. It's not an AIR project. It's usual flex project running within flash player.

Comment: How Flash Builder know which version of SDK used, I think somewhere it must be written.

Comment: i think when you import a project, your FB would try to apply the default SDK that you have set for your project. Are you getting an error after importing the project?

Comment: Yes I get compilation errors and red 'x' marks on every project icon. Currently I have installed latest Flash Bulder (v4.5) and it comes with 3.6 and 4.5 Flex SDK versions, but it seems none from mentioned SDK's is compatible with my project.

Comment: I found this line htmlPlayerVersion="9.0.28"

Comment: Then it should be a Flex 3.0 project, see if you can get hold of the 3.0 or 3.1 SDK and add it to your FB compiler list...

Comment: I think so. Anyway I'm going to try 3.0 or 3.1 SDK. Thank you silverback.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on project folder in flash builder, then property, then flex compilator.

Comment: Nothing interesting there. Only Use Default SDK(currently "Flex 4.5") or Use a specific SDK.