# flash builder: how to find project version

Tags: flash, apache-flex, version, builder

I developed a rudimentary project in Flex a couple of years ago, but I don't remember the flex version I used. 
I searched through project's xml files, but could't find it.
Can someone give me a clue?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239503/how-to-know-exact-flex-sdk-version-from-existing-project-files

Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have the old index.html that was generated in bin-debug, look for the minimum flash player version and that should give you a clue.

---

The following is a list of Flex SDK versions and the Flash Player versions they target by default:

```
SDK     FP
4.6  -  11.1
4.5  -  10.2
4.1  -  10.1
4.0  -  10
3.5  -  9.0.124
```

Comment: Good thinking. I happen to have a list lying around that pairs up player versions with SDK versions in this manner. If you don't mind me editing your answer, I'll add them.

Comment: I don't have any index.html. It's an AIR desktop application. Is there any other place I can find the targeted flash version?

Comment: I found the version, based on flextras' answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Flash Builder, you can bring up your project properties, then choose Flex Compiler.

You'll either see the workspace default SDK selected or a specific SDK.

If you have used the default SDK and have changed it since you built the project; I don't think there is a way to know which SDK you used to compile the project in the past.

---

You could also use a SWF Decompiler to decompile the code from your SWF.  [SoThink has one](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/); but I believe there are others.  If you did not use RSLs for the framework originally; then all the framework code will be compiled into your SWF and you may be able to parse the framework code to figure it out.  A lot of framework files include a 'version.as' file which should tell you if you can find it in the source.

If you did compile the app using RSLs for the framework, then looking at the the SWF / SWZ files in your deployment directory should tell you the version.  For example, one app I'm working on has these files: mx_4.5.1.21489.swz, rpc_4.5.1.21328.swz, spark_4.5.1.21489.swz, etc..  I can tell that the app was compiled from Flex 4.5.1.

Comment: that is the problem, I reinstalled my OS since then and just installed flash builder 4.5, which comes with flex 3.6, 4.5 and 4.5.1. by default, 4.5.1 is selected but that didn't exist at the time I developed project.

Comment: I added a few more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, flextras! I decompiled the swf and found the flash version, which lead me to the flex version, based on Trish Rempel's answer.